# Converting list with nested list to a separate list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm building an application for a game. On my form I have a datagridview to which I would like to bind the choices that were made by the different players.

I have a specific PlayerClass which I have put in a list called Players.

```
public class PlayerClass
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public List<bool> choices {get; set;}
}

Public List<PlayerClass> Players;
```

In this list I will add the choices made by the players for the different questions.

To display the choices made, I want to combine the results into a datagridview where I have one column for every player andwhere every row represents the answer given by that player for that specific question.

So I was thinking of creating a list with a new Class which holds all the answers that were given by the different players for a question.

```
public class ChoicesViewClass
{
    public bool ChoicePlayer1 { get; set; }
    public bool ChoicePlayer2 { get; set; }
    public bool ChoicePlayer3 { get; set; }
    public bool ChoicePlayer4 { get; set; }
}
```

But how can I use Linq to populate the Choices in the secondary list from the first list?

I was trying something like this:

```
grdChoices.DataSource = Players
                      .Select(s => new ChoicesViewClass{ ChoicePlayer1 = s, ChoicePlayer2 = s, ChoicePlayer3 = s, ChoicePlayer4 = s })
                      .ToList();
```

But the `s` is where I am stuck. 
How can I solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Well you are trying to access the player choices by index? will the player choices list have 4 length by default? This will solve your problem:

```
grdChoices.DataSource = Players
                      .Select(s => new ChoicesViewClass{ ChoicePlayer1 = s.choices[0], ChoicePlayer2 = s.choices[1], ChoicePlayer3 = s.choices[2], ChoicePlayer4 = s.choices[3] })
                      .ToList();
```

But i'm a bit confused, why complicate it to much? why can't the player have a property of ChoicesViewClass? like so :

```
public class PlayerClass
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public ChoicesViewClass choices {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Well there is already a list in the Playerclass where I'm storing true or false. So choices[0] will be the choice for question 1, choices[1] will contain the choice for question 2 etc... I have 4 player that can take part in the game, so I want to see the answers for the 4 players in a grid next to each other for easy comparison. I can't use the ChoicesViewClass in my Playerclass, because the ChoicesViewClass contains the answers for 4 players. While the Playerclass is for each player individual.